# unable to add scrollbar to svg

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

i m trying to add scroll bar to the div which contains my svg doing this

```
<div id="d3div" style="height: 70%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;">


var svg = d3.select("#d3div").append("svg")
         .attr("width", '100%')
         .attr("height", '100%')
        .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

Acc to theory the svg dimensions should be greater than div so i did here. and i dont want to specify the svg dimensions in pixels..but if i give like above the div dosent show any scroll bar..please help

Comment: You are attempting to append svg inside the `#d3div` wha will happen means it inherit `height:100%` from `d3div 's height:100%`.so it doest get large than `#d3div`.

Comment: so how do i make it smaller without using size in pixels..if i use svg size in px then it always shows a scrollbar even if the elements dun cross the page..i want it more of dynamic sense

Comment: and i m using div height:70%

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9fLsy1cs/3/ jsut check this example now. is that you need

Comment: Hope you get that now.

Comment: yes..exactly but everything works fine with text but when i add d3 nodes the thing dosent work..as svg needs predefined dimensions

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `overflow:auto` for the SVG which is inside the '#d3Div'

just create a class `.d3`

```
.d3{
  height:70%; overflow:hidden;
}

.d3 svg{
  height:100%; overflow:auto;
}
   <div id="d3div" class="d3"></div>
```

this is the way to obtain your resut.

[**JUST CHECK THIS FIDDLE TOO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9fLsy1cs/5/)